# Displays a string of linked images

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, terms, query-string

How do I displays a string of linked images for a post using php?

Terms
`http://domain.com/106.jpg,http://domain.com/109.jpg,http://domain.com/112.jpg`

```
    <div class="gallery" ><?php the_field( 'gallery' ); ?></div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `explode()` function:

```
$string = 'http://domain.com/106.jpg,http://domain.com/109.jpg,http://domain.com/112.jpg';
$split = explode ( ',', $string );
```

It will return an array. So you can print this way:

```
echo $split[0]; //will print http://domain.com/106.jpg
echo $split[1]; //will print http://domain.com/109.jpg
//and so on
```

Comment: Great! And how do you display these images from a Wordpress custom field? `the_field( 'gallery' );`

Comment: `the_field()` is not a wordpress function, probably a plugin function. Questions regarding plugins are off topic.


If `the_field( 'gallery' )` contains the example string. Then you can just change 1st line of my code to `$string = the_field( 'gallery' );`

Comment: Dually noted. `echo $split[0];` returns an array at the end of the url `array(1) { [0]=> string(0)`, is their an alternative way to print?

Comment: Add the exact return value of `var_dump(the_field( 'gallery' ));`

Comment: `http://domain.com/106.jpg,http://domain.com/109.jpg,http://domain.com/112.jpgNull` Without `var_dump` and `echos` it returns `http://domain.com/106.jpg,http://domain.com/109.jpg,http://domain.com/112.jpg`

Comment: Instead of `the_field()`, use `get_field()` in above code.

Comment: Also tried `get_field` no luck. and `<?php 
          
$string = the_field( 'other' );
$split = explode ( '|', $string );

echo "<li><img src='{echo $split}' /></li>";

var_dump(the_field( 'other' ));

?>`

Comment: Your code should be: `<?php             $string = get_field( 'other' ); $split = explode ( '|', $string );  echo "<li><img src='{$split[0]}' /></li>";  var_dump(get_field( 'other' ));  ?>`

and what is the return value for `var_dump(get_field( 'other' ));` ?

Comment: `var_dump` is NULL without any src.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far @Sufi. An image prints with `<?php 
          
$string = 'http://domain.com/106.jpg,http://domain.com/109.jpg,http://domain.com/112.jpg';
$split = explode ( '|', $string );

echo $split[0]; //will print http://domain.com/106.jpg

?>' but not with `get_field( 'other' );`

Comment: If `var_dump(get_field( 'other' ));` returns `NULL`, that means there is nothing in `other`.

Comment: This is what worked in the end `<?php

$string = get_field( 'other' );
$split = explode ( '|', $string );
echo "<li><img src='{$split[0]}' /></li>";
echo "<li><img src='{$split[1]}' /></li>";

?>` thanks heaps :)

Comment: This is what I have suggested you to execute 5 comments ago from this one!